# Phalcon php hash same password produces multiple result

Tags: php, hash, phalcon

I use this statement to hash the password with Phalcon:
**$hashedPassword= $this->security->hash($password)**

but this statement returns different results with the same password.

Example:
Set $password=**123**
I get $hashedPassword with the following values:

**$2a$08$T2Rf9IcQHTj7TpY.gsfGiexZ35/KK9kS3fLElxaw8LGXhjnE01f5K**
and
**$2a$08$E2mjApECMbRKQFZodgLkEOpDLSV/tEjTe1HV3q2LLG9UINj9M9GBm**
and 
**$2a$08$aZmgsMmG2xRueVzP6tkx2ucWGPZMzUwIccXbLJnqoRwDsSnT4zc.q**

---

Here is the code I use for checking user's password,
please let me know what am I missing.

```
if ($this->request->isPost() == true)
{
    $email = $this->request->getPost ("email");
    $password = $this->request->getPost ("password");

    $conditions = "email = ?1 AND admin = ?2";
    $parameters = array(1 => $email, 2 => 1);

    $users = Users::findFirst(array(
        $conditions,
        "bind" => $parameters
    ));

    if($users)
    {
        $security = new Phalcon\Security();
        $checkHashValue = $security->checkHash($password, $user->password);
        if($checkHashValue)
        {
            $this->flash->success($users->fullname);
        }
        else
        {
            //Print debug information
            $hash = $security->hash($password);

            $checkHash = $security->checkHash($password, $hash);

            $this->flash->error("Password: ". $password. 
            "<br/>Hash: " . $hash . "<br/>Check Hash: " . $checkHash . 
            "<br/>Check HashValue: ". $checkHashValue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->flash->error($password);
    }
}
```

---

**SOLUTION:** I have a typo in my variable "user" instead of "users".

Answer (score 1):

That's how it is supposed to work. It creates a random hash each time. To check the password use `security->checkPassword()`

Comment: I have posted my code. I have use the security->checkPassword(). Please let me know what I'm missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** I have a typo in my variable "user" instead of "users".